# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'subs'

Tags: python-3.x

I am making a definition which will help me replace the varials of a polynomial but I get this error

```
from sympy import *

x = Symbol('x')
def velocidad_media(t0,t1,poli):
    D1=poli.subs(x,t0)
    D0=poli.subs(x,t1)
    D3=D1-D0
    T= t1-t0
    Re=D3/T
    print("la velocidad media es",Re,"m/s")

pol=input("ingrese la funcion del lanzamiento: ")
a= int(input("ingrese el tiempo inicial en segundos: "))
b=int(input("ingrese el tiempo final en segundos: "))
punt=int(input("ingrese el punto en donde quiere hallar la velocidad instantanea: "))velocidad_media(a,b,pol)`
```

Error message :

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'subs'
```

Answer (score 2):

The `input` returns a `str` type, but you are treating it as a sympy expression.
What you can do it to parse the string `pol` into an sympy expression with the function `parse_expr`.
e.g.

```py
from sympy import *
from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import parse_expr

x = Symbol('x')
pol = parse_expr('x**2 + x + 1')
pol.subs(x,1)
```