# sympy:AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'subs'?

Tags: python, sympy

How should i fix it

https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/basic_operations.html

```
from sympy import *
var('ax')
ans_a=ax
print("#",ans_a)
myValue={ax:6}
print("#",ans_a.subs(myValue))
#
var('bx')
ans_b=[bx]
print("#",ans_b)
myValue={bx:7}
print("#",ans_b.subs(myValue))
# ax
# 6
# [bx]
# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'subs'
# I want
# [7]
```

???

[AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'subs'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58760606/attributeerror-str-object-has-no-attribute-subs)

https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

Comment: Use a list comprehension

Comment: `[bx]` is a list.  That's basic python.  A sympy expression has a `subs` method,  A list does not.

Comment: `print("#", [ans.subs(myValue) for ans in ans_b])`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why I can't use subs with sympy? // 'list' object has no attribute 'subs'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68567525/why-i-cant-use-subs-with-sympy-list-object-has-no-attribute-subs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I searched about subs

```
from sympy import *
var('bx')
ans_b=[bx]
print("#",ans_b)
myValue={bx:7}
print("#", [ans.subs(myValue) for ans in ans_b])
#
var('m11 m12 m21 m22')
ans_M= Matrix([[m11,m12], [m21,m22]])
print("#",ans_M)
myValue={m11:11,m12:12,m21:21,m22:22}
print("#",ans_M.subs(myValue))
#
var('px py')
ans_P=Point(px,py)
print("#",ans_P)
myValue={px:1,py:2}
print("#",ans_P.subs(myValue))
# [bx]
# [7]
# Matrix([[m11, m12], [m21, m22]])
# Matrix([[11, 12], [21, 22]])
# Point2D(px, py)
# Point2D(1, 2)
```

Comment: A sympy matrix and a sympy point are sympy objects and support a long list of sympy methods.   A Python list, however, doesn't support sympy methods. This is how libraries in Python work, they can't add new "methods" to existing Python objects. Note that a "method" is different to a "function". See e.g. [this tutorial](https://data-flair.training/blogs/python-method/).